# valuechangelistener getting called multiple time

Tags: jsf-2, weblogic12c, icefaces-3

I'm working on icefaces upgrade from 1.8 to 3.3  as well as jsf from 1.2 to 2.0.

I have used this link as reference for icefaces [upgrade](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Converting+ICEfaces+1.8+Applications+to+ICEfaces+3)

I'm using ice:datatable in which I have column of checkbox which is grouped for single worker.Check picture which is of [before upgrade](http://postimg.org/image/ppae2dzd9/).

ISSUE 1:
Now Problem faced after migration is that the valuechangelistener of ice:selectbooleancheckbox  works fine when I check then uncheck the checkbox of a single worker. But when I do following steps:

1. Check first worker (This updates the Assigned door column ).
2. Then check other worker . This unchecks the previous checked worker and also unchecks currently checked worker.

To analyse if there is any issue in phase I used balus C blog to check phase of icefaces when it hits valuechangelistner . Then I found on my second check 2 or more valuechangelistner are called one for previous worker other for current worker(Sometimes twice) this all happens in same invoke application phase.

ISSUE 2:
ValueChangeListener gets called even after Clicking "OK" button or "CANCEL".
Fixed it by adding f:param in ice:commandButton and checking for the param in valuechangelistener method.

Tried:

1. To change all ice tags in the page to ace tags(Related to datatable i.e datable ,row  and column).

Result : Same issue with ace valuechangelistener as well as distorted style. Maybe because I could not find ice:rowHeader equivalent in ace tags and also much more.

2. Changed only checkbox column to ace:column. Valuechangelistener worked fine but issue with "groupOn" attribute so changed it to  "groupBy" and condition="group" still may be it did not work because I used ice:datatable which doesn't support it.
3. Then I tried to implement groupOn functionality manually. Using rowspan and rendering single checkbox for single worker . But rowspan didn't work. Also when I tried to render checkbox, its style is not exactly same as I need. Check this hattp://postimg.org/image/ih2mgoh7d/ remove 'a' from 'hattp'.

   ```
    <ace:column groupBy ="#{item.workerName} + #{item.workerId}" rowspan="2" 
                           styleClass= "alignSBChbx" >
                           <ice:setEventPhase events="ValueChangeEvent"
                                      phase="INVOKE_APPLICATION">
                           <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox id="dwaCheckbox"  value="#{item.select}" 
                          style=" width:'#{appViewSettings.checkboxSize}';
                           height:'#{appViewSettings.checkboxSize}';" 
                           valueChangeListener="#{dockWorkerAssignmentBean.doorAssignmentChange}" 
                           partialSubmit="true" immediate="true" 
                           disabled="#{!empty dockWorkerAssignmentBean.errorMap['dockWorkersAssignmentPopup:assignmentErrorField']}"
                           rendered="#{item.visible}">
                           <f:attribute name="workerIdSelected" value="#{item.workerId}" />
                           <f:attribute name="assignmentIdSelected" value="#{item.assignmentId}" />
                           </ice:selectBooleanCheckbox>

                           </ice:setEventPhase>
                           </ace:column>






     backend
     public final void doorAssignmentChange(final ValueChangeEvent event) {
   System.out.println("inside door Assignment...");


     final String workerIdSelected = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get(
           "workerIdSelected");
    // unrelevant code

    }
   ```

   }

Comment: To exclude one and other, are you `binding` the data table component to a session scoped bean? If so, try removing it and retest.

Comment: No I'm not binding data

Comment: Means not explicitly . but yes its bean is in session scope in faces-config . In which scope should I put it? or remove it completely ? Thanks for the response

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I was trying to handle it in other way. Ok I tried by removing scope of bean but getting some other issue in populating data due to request scope. That won't work for me. I'm trying to create new bean with request scope and then call valuechangelistener of session scope bean not passing valuechangelistener event but jst essential parameters from event.

Comment: Ok even that could not help me. Anyway I have somehow managed to create functionality of groupon with ice:datatable and ace:column using render and changes in few extra variables in model.